# Python + OpenCV + Base64: Issue with converting frame to base64

Tags: python, opencv, base64

I am trying to convert a video to frames and those frames to base64 strings. I am unable to do so and getting some exceptions. Below is my code:

```
import cv2
import base64


def footage_to_frame(video):
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    success, frames = vidcap.read()
    if success:
        return frames


def frame_to_base64(frames):
    with frames as frame:
        frame_b64 = base64.b64encode(frame.read())
    return frame_b64
```

The function calls to this method are:

```
frames = converter.footage_to_frame("/Users/myname/Desktop/video.mp4")
converter.frame_to_base64(frames)
```

Below is the error I get in console:

```
File "/Users/myname/Desktop/Test/src/service/converter.py", line 13, in frame_to_base64
    with frames as frame:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function frame_to_base64(frames), frames is already a single image because VideoCapture.read returns a single image. Also it is a opencv image (numpy array) which is not something you can use "with" on.

```
def frame_to_base64(frame):
    return base64.b64encode(frame)
```

If you want to read all frames of video, you should do something like:

```
import cv2
import base64


def footage_to_frame(video):
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    frames = []

    #  read until no more frames exist in the video
    while True:
        success, frame = vidcap.read()
        if (success):
            frames.append(frame)
        else:
            #  unable to read a frame
            break
 
    return frames


def frames_to_base64(frames):
    frames_b64 = []
    #  iterate frames and convert each of them to base64
    for frame in frames:
        frames_b64.append(base64.b64encode(frame))
    return frames_b64
```

Although depending on video length, you may experience memory problems.